# Using autocode I have made a discord chatbot but there is one small issue. the only way ive been able to get it to reply to me is by pinging it

Tags: discord, chatbot, autocode

Basically I have this chatbot but it won't reply to replies, yknow when you hover over a message and click that nice reply button, the only way ive been able to get it to reply is by @'ing it, however it doesnt do this in discord servers, only in dms. is there any way i can get it to just reply in dms whenever a message is sent or if I replied to one of its messages without pinging it?

Here is all the code I had used from Autocode

```
/**
 * An HTTP endpoint that acts as a webhook for Discord bot_mention event
 * @param {object} event
 * @returns {any} result
 */
module.exports = async (event, context) => {

  const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

  let author = context.params.event.author;
  let botMention = context.params.event.mentions.find(mentio => mention.bot);
  let newMessage = context.params.event.content;
  let historyKey = `character_bot__${author.id}_chat`;
  let historyLength = 10; // 5 back-and-forth messages
  let historyTTL = 600; // 10 minutes

  let chatHistory = await lib.utils.kv['@0.1.16'].get({
    key: historyKey,
    defaultValue: [],
  });

  let acknowledgementMessage = await lib.discord.channels['@0.3.4'].messages.create({
    channel_id: `1136506915342532630`,
    content: `...`,
    message_reference: {
      message_id: context.params.event.id,
      fail_if_not_exists: false
    }
  });

  let messages = [];

  messages.push({
    role: 'system',
    content: [
    ].join('\n')
  });

  messages = messages.concat(chatHistory);

  messages.push({
    role: 'user',
    content: `${newMessage}`,
  });

  let completionResponse = await lib.openai.playground['@0.2.2'].chat.completions.create({
    model: `gpt-3.5-turbo`,
    messages,
    max_tokens: 1024,
    temperature: 0.5,
    top_p: 1,
    n: 1,
    presence_penalty: 0.25,
    frequency_penalty: 0.1
  });

  let message = completionResponse.choices[0].message.content;

  await lib.discord.channels['@0.3.4'].messages.update({
    message_id: acknowledgementMessage.id,
    channel_id: `1136506915342532630`,
    content: `${message}`,
  });

  chatHistory.push(
    {
      role: 'user',
      content: `${newMessage}`
    },
    {
      role: 'assistant',
      content: `${message}`
    },
  );

  await lib.utils.kv['@0.1.16'].set({
    key: historyKey,
    value: chatHistory.slice(-historyLength),
    ttl: historyTTL,
  });



};
```

I have tried looking for ways around this and every time it has not worked.

Comment: So I have just discovered something, I tried again and it suddenly works but for some reason won't reply to my friend